# Map markers for OpenLayer map Tiled layers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I need to put some map markers on an OpenLayer map. The map is populated from Geoserver.
I have more layers, this is one of it:

```
case "cite:geo_poli_intabulareNouFiltered":
            var userId = $("#loggedInUserId").val();
            layers.push(
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: overlays[i].Item2,
                    type: 'overlay',
                    preload: Infinity,
                    visible: false,
                    layer: overlays[i].Item1,
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
                        url: GeoServer + "/geoserver/gwc/service/",
                        params: { 'LAYERS': overlays[i].Item1, 'VERSION': '1.1.1', 'service': 'wms', 'tiled': true, viewparams: 'UserId:' + userId },
                        serverType: 'geoserver'
                    })
                })
            );
            break;
```

It looks like this:
 [image]

I can filter this layer with some values from database,and the result should contain a map marker. This is how it looks after the filter:
[image]

The result should contain a map marker, too.

This is the code that it is used for filtering, and at the end of this code I should put the map marker for the result.

```
  filterCondition: function () {
    var myConditions = this.composeConditions(),
        _layers,
        i,
        layer,
        source,
        layerParams,
        cql_filter,
        opacity,
        j,
        element,
        conditionSeparator,
        conditions;

    _layers = map.getLayers().getArray();
    conditionSeparator = '';

    myConditions.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
        conditions = element;
        for (i = 0; i < _layers.length; i++) {
            if ((_layers[i].get('type') == 'overlay') && _layers[i].getVisible()) {
                layer = _layers[i].get('layer');
                console.log("Layer " + layer);
                source = _layers[i].getSource();
                console.log(source);
                layerParams = source.getParams();
                console.log(layerParams);
                cql_filter = [];
                console.log(layer);
                for (j = 0 ; j < conditions.length; j++) {
                    element = conditions[j];
                    if (element['layer'] == layer) {
                        var value = $.trim(element['val'].toLowerCase());

                        console.log(value);
                        if (value == "null") {                               
                            cql_filter.push("strToLowerCase(" + element['prop'] + ") " + "is null");
                        }
                        else {
                            if (value.length > 0) {
                                if (element['cond'] === "like") {
                                    cql_filter.push("strToLowerCase(" + element['prop'] + ") " + element['cond'] + " '%" + value + "%'");
                                } else {
                                    if ($.isNumeric(value)) {
                                        cql_filter.push(element['prop'] + " " + element['cond'] + " " + value);
                                    } else {
                                        cql_filter.push(element['prop'] + " " + element['cond'] + " '" + value + "'");
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (element['cond'] === "like") {
                                    cql_filter.push("strToLowerCase(" + element['prop'] + ") " + element['cond'] + " ''");
                                } else {
                                    cql_filter.push(element['prop'] + " " + element['cond'] + " ''");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        conditionSeparator = element['match_condition'];
                    }
                }

                if (conditionSeparator != '') {
                    if (conditionSeparator !== 'NOT') {
                        cql_filter = cql_filter.join(" " + conditionSeparator + " ");
                    } else {
                        cql_filter = 'NOT ' + cql_filter.join(" AND ");
                    }
                } else {
                    cql_filter = cql_filter.join(" AND ");
                }
                if (cql_filter != "") {
                    console.log("The generated condition for the group #" + element['groupId'] + ": " + cql_filter);

                    /*var firstIndex = cql_filter.indexOf("'") + 1;
                    var lastIndex = cql_filter.lastIndexOf("'");
                    var initialDate = cql_filter.substring(firstIndex, lastIndex);

                    var arr = initialDate.split('/');
                    var aux = arr[0];
                    arr[0] = arr[1];
                    arr[1] = aux;
                    var newDate = arr[2] + "-" + arr[0] + "-" + arr[1];
                    cql_filter = cql_filter.replace(initialDate, newDate)*/


                    layerParams.cql_filter = cql_filter;
                    layerParams.opacity = 0.1;
                    source.updateParams(layerParams);
                    alert("filter");
                    console.log(source);

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Can you advise in this case?

I have Tiled layers. I have no experience with `Openlayers` and `Geoserver`. I've tried some methods that I have founded on the net, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

you can find solutions in openlayer examples itself. For better understanding, in openlayer every thing is in forms of layers for different purposes. so here you tried tiled layer to display your map and now you can use vector/webglpoints layers to display marker points
webgl renders pretty quick and works well with even 200k points I tried personally also applied several operations like drag and drop points to new location and much more

[webglpoints layer](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-points-layer.html)

[vector layer with points](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html)

here the vector layer is using marker image you can also replace image in webglpoints layer to render the same.